# Multiple Step definition files with Codecept Gherkin

Tags: javascript, automation, gherkin, codeceptjs

I'm currently working with a Codecept's Gherkin framework. At the moment my step definition file is huge (1000+ lines) and I want to break it down to smaller, more maintainable chunks but I haven't been able to find a way of doing with codecept and google hasn't been much of a help.

In the codecept config file the step definition files are referenced in an array, which leads me to believe that multiple step definition files is possible.

```
  gherkin: {
features: './features/**/*.feature',
steps: [
        './step_definitions/step_definition_file.js'
      ]
}
```

I tried adding multiple files with different steps in each but when I run a feature with steps specified in a file that is not first in the array then it doesn't work(step not specified error).

So how can I specify, in codecept which step definition file a feature is suppose to use?

Comment: I'm looking at how to solve this as well. I find no clue about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone coming across this post this is the solution

In codecept.config file you steps config should look like this

```
gherkin: {
  features: './features/**/*.feature',
  steps: './step_definitions/**/*.js'
}
```